# Training Keras model with multiple CSV files in multi folder in python

Tags: python, csv, keras, conv-neural-network

I have eight folders with 1300 CSV files (3*50) in each folder, each folder represents a label, but I have no idea how to input my data in to a training model.
Still, a beginner in CNN.

A part of my csv file can be accessed using this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGOCV.jpg).

Comment: I should ask you to be more clear, describe your data format? Do all the csv's in all folders make whole dataset? If so, then you should use `pandas` and collect your data "by hand".

Comment: All files are 50 row and 3 col which means they are the same size and all folder has the same amount of files all of this make my whole dataset, and the data in my files represent a Three-axis changes in a second, I tried pandas but I am still having trouble dealing with non image data.

Answer (score 0):

When using Keras, you can use the `tf.data.Dataset` package, which helps you doing what you want to achieve.

**Example**

Here is an example code, I took from one of my projects:

```
# matching a glob pattern!
dataset_pro_raw = tf.data.Dataset.list_files([f"./aclImdb/{name}/pos/*.txt"], shuffle=True)
dataset_pro_i = dataset_pro_raw.interleave(
        lambda file: tf.data.TextLineDataset(file),
        # how many files should be processed concurently
        cycle_length = 20,
        # number of threads to increase the performance
        num_parallel_calls = 10
    )
```

First, we create a filelist by `tf.data.Dataset.list_files()`, also note, that already there the order of the files is shuffled. Then via `dataset_pro_raw.interleave()` we iterate through the file set and read the content of the files with with `tf.data.TextLineDataset()`.

That way you can load data from multiple .txt files or any data source very well. It is a big clumsy at the beginning ot use, but it has very well advantages. Currently I only use `tf.data.Dataset` for train-data generation.

For more information on `tf.data.Dataset` you might want to check out this [link](https://canvas.education.lu.se/courses/3766/pages/chapter-13-loading-and-preprocessing-data-with-tensorflow)

Comment: it looks good with single folder but i dont know how to get to other folders with it,and separate it to different labels